# Syntax error with Toast

Tags: android, android-listview, toast

```
List<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
.
.
.
.
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{

    //super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(ListPage.this, items[position].sid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Getting an error with the Toast, the error says "type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to List[ListItems]." Need to know wat the correct way of writing the Toast is

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
items[position].sid
```

By

```
items.get(position).sid //Assuming sid is a type of String
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use String.valueOf() to display `int` value.

```
  Toast.makeText(ListPage.this, String.valueOf(  items.get(position)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: @AbhijeetLimaye: Right my ans !

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Toast.makeText(ListPage.this, items.get(position).sid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Not sure what `sid` is in your case

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

**Parameters**

- `context`: The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.
- `text`: The text to show. Can be formatted text.
- `duration`: How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG

**Android's documentation on Toasts**

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

**Check the documentation**

- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29)

**Example**

Use the get method of arraylist with index position to display the toast.

```
ArrayList<String> mystring = new ArrayList<String>();
mystring.add("hello");
Toast.makeText(ListPage.this, mystring.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```